# link to update model parameter yields missing or empty value error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, update-attributes

I'm trying to give provide a series of links that when selected will update a corresponding user's parameter to that which is supplied by the link without rendering a form. The only problem I'm running into is that when it calls the update method I get: **param is missing or the value is empty: user**.

**update method**

```
 def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update(user_params)
  redirect_to list_path
  flash[:success] = "User updated"
else
  redirect_to list_path
  flash[:alert] = "User not updated"
end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :title, :role, :address, :phone)
end
```

**link_to**

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
        <% if user.role == "new" %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.title %></td>
        <td><%= user.role %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Admin", update_user_path(id: user.id, :role => "admin"), :method => :put %> / <%= link_to "Moderator", '#' %> / <%= link_to "Member", '#' %> / <%= link_to "Other", '#' %></td>
      </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

**param.inspect**

```
{"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"AUcV1swtGmRuDelTzLkbLd9Gmj6+phnHaSFRqrvDyETLoxNUQSaAgkes4ViWXoAZ33K5NZojVz9XdgIIsqJblA==",
"id"=>"2",
"role"=>"admin"}
```

From what I've found the params.inspect should have something like `[:user] =>` before all the parameters listed, but I cannot figure out why it is not nor can I successfully find a way to clarify.

**error:**
**param is missing or the value is empty: user**

```
def user_params     
  **params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,**
                               :password_confirmation, :title, :role, :address, :phone)
end
end
```

**Log after link select**

```
Started PUT "/update_user?id=4&role=admin" for 97.78.175.155 at 2015-06-30   15:51:47 +0000
Cannot render console from 97.78.175.155! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"m+LcLOBL5NBXHQXD19o45/iV07/V1HiAXpykV+NiXIpRBtqubUB+Nn68DciNPaPT+KHwtPFRNnhgy/f16gPPWg==", "id"=>"4", "role"=>"admin"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
Unpermitted parameters: _method, authenticity_token, id
       (0.2ms)  begin transaction
          User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('qwerty@poster.com') AND "users"."id" != 4) LIMIT 1
       (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to https://rails-tutorial-hougthonbrad.c9.io/list
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/list" for 97.78.175.155 at 2015-06-30 15:51:47 +0000
Cannot render console from 97.78.175.155! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#list as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered users/list.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 172ms (Views: 165.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ***update*** action to the below.

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update(user_params)
  redirect_to list_path
  flash[:success] = "User updated"
else
  redirect_to list_path
  flash[:alert] = "User not updated"
end
end
```

***Update #1:***

Looking at your ***params***, you need to change your `user_params` like the below.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title, :role, :address, :phone)
end
```

***Update #2:***

Try changing your `link_to` to the below

```
<%= link_to "Admin", update_user_path(user, user: {:id => user.id, :role => "admin"}), :method => :put %>
```

Comment: It's still highlighting the user_params and displaying the same error.

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Please update your post with complete error log.

Comment: I've added a few more details to the post

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Ok. Can you also post the form which is used for update?

Comment: If you're referring to a `form_for` I'm trying to update this single parameter without using a form and indicating what to assign to it based on the link selected (i.e. admin / moderator / member / blacklisted)

Comment: I'm not getting the missing or empty parameter error, but it's not actually updating.

Comment: @Houghtonbrad I need your log. Did you see something like **Started Patch**, then please copy that full and post it in your question.

Comment: I'm getting a new error saying `unknown attribute '_method' for user`.

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Check now. Remove `_method` and `authencity_token` from `user_params` and change the `link_to` like above.

Comment: new error: `couldn't find User with 'id'=`  edit: that was after I fiddled with it. Your suggestion just didn't update the user

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Does my updated `link_to` work with your old `user_params` included with `:id`?

Comment: When I use your `link_to` with `update_user_path` instead of `user_path` which I think you meant with my old params including `:id` I get the `couldn't find User with 'id'=` error.    parameter request includes `{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XAqV3pzmlOY+aPtB5+9JZzcJKY1Z/99ocOJ0FQjm8ieW7pNcEe0OABfJ80q9CNJTNz0Khn16kZBOtSe3AYdh9w==",
 "user"=>{"role"=>"admin"},
 "format"=>"2"}`

Comment: @Houghtonbrad What happens when you change `user: {:role => "admin"}` to `user: {:id => user.id, :role => "admin"}`?

Comment: Same deal only `{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Js3G62W8DrmzdjqU2Tx8lRl+WKYdtDkcmM0B51dlF1DsKcBp6LeUX5rXMp+D2+ehGUp7rTkxd+SmmlJFXgSEgA==",
 "user"=>{"id"=>"2",
 "role"=>"admin"},
 "format"=>"2"}` is listed in the parameters.

Comment: yes, `couldn't find User with 'id'=` still shows up.

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Can you check my updated answer and confirm is that what you have now?

Comment: copied and pasted. Still yielding the same error screen

Comment: @Houghtonbrad Try changing this `<%= link_to "Admin", update_user_path(user, user: {:id => user.id, :role => "admin"}), :method => :put %>` to `<%= link_to "Admin", update_user_path(user: {:id => user.id, :role => "admin"}), :method => :put %>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `params.require(:user)` within your user_params. 
That `user` hash is usually generated by `form_for`.

I would suggest to render a form with all fields hidden except the submit button for your use case.

Comment: I try that and I'm back to square one. I'm begining ton think it's my update method itself.

Comment: I'm not sure how up to date your question and errors are. Would suggest that you write a separate method for updating user roles, instead of relying on the generic `update` method. This will allow you to `permit` the specific attributes you need.